# PowerShell testing if file is in folder Error

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell code where I want to check if in folder is file containing certain pattern.

If there is a file with certain pattern then I want to continue the work.

I have it as this:

```
$path = "c:\test\"
$Pattern = "1044"
$1044 = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where {$_.Name -match $Pattern}
$strFileName = "C:\test\" + $1044

if (Test-Path $strFileName) {
    ...
}
```

The issue is that the code keeps running even though the file with the pattern isn't there.

I printed the `$1044` and it says

> Can't find file

I printed also out the `if` condition and it says:

> Can't find file True

That's why the code is running but I really don't understand why.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't do this with Test-Path alone?   It looks like you don't understand that object(s) returned in $1044 are not strings, but file or directory objects.

Comment: e.g. `If (Test-Path c:\test\1044) { ... }

Comment: Hi, the thing is that there is changing name in 1044 file - it can be 1044_2745924 or 1044_9573 .. And I am lost how to write it simply and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `$1044 = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where {$_.Name -match $Pattern}` could return any number of results (zero, one, or more).

If it returns zero results the variable `$1044` will be empty, so `$strFileName = "C:\test\" + $1044` will evaluate to just `C:\test\`, which `Test-Path` will (correctly) report as existing.

If it returns more than one result he variable `$1044` will contain a list of file or folder objects. Doing `$strFileName = "C:\test\" + $1044` will mangle this list into a space-separated string of the file/folder names and append that to the base path (meaning you'll get something like `C:\test\1044foo bar1044 1044_baz` instead of `C:\test\1044foo`, `C:\test\bar1044`, `C:\test\1044_baz`). This path doesn't exist, so `Test-Path` will always evaluate to false in that situation.

Besides, you don't need to build `$strFileName` by string concatenation in the first place (unless your base path is different from the path used with `Get-ChildItem`), because the objects returned by `Get-ChildItem` already have a property with the full path (`FullName`). And you also don't need to test the paths for existence, because `Get-ChildItem` wouldn't have returned an item if it didn't exist.

Change your code to something like this:

```
$1044 = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $Pattern} 

if ($1044) {
    ...
}
```

and it should do what you expect, because PowerShell evaluates `$1044` to `$false` if it's empty and to `$true` if it isn't.

Comment: Hi I dont get why also now the PShell evaluates the condition like this:  
    $1044 = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $Pattern} 

print($1044) like Can't find file 10433_20180928.xlsx  when it is there

Comment: @HeadOverFeet PowerShell does not have a cmdlet, function or alias `print`, so `print($1044)` would normally (try to) invoke `print.exe`, which would print a text file to the default printer device PRN. Also, neither `Get-ChildItem` nor `Where-Object` produce the output "Can't find file". I'd suspect that you made some modifications to your environment (in a profile) causing non-standard PowerShell behavior. Please try again in a clean PowerShell console (`powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoExit`).

Answer (score 0):

If your patern is not complicated, you can use test-path with wildcard, not necessary to use get-childitem

```
$Path="C:\test\*"
$Patern="*1044*"

if (Test-Path -Path $Path -Filter $Patern -PathType Leaf)
{
    "File whith patern exist"
}
```